# How to search text in html with JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

i tried to search text in my html code with jquery but no luck
this is my code:

```
    $("body").on("searchByLikuy", function(e, msg) {
        msg = msg.replace(/'/g, "\'");
        found = $("*:contains('" + msg + "'):last");
        if(found.length > 0) {
            $('html, body').stop(true).animate({
                scrollTop: found.offset().top - 30
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

When the html code is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test">
    abcde
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and i searching the msg "abcde"
its working fine and return in "found" variable what i need.
but when the html code is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test">
    <span>a</span>
    <span>b</span>
    <span>c</span>
    <span>d</span>
    <span>e</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

its not returning anything.
what can i do to searching ?

tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can try simply :

```
if( $("body").text().includes(msg) ) { ...
```

Or with a regex :

```
if( new RegExp(msg, "i").test( $("body").text() )) { ...
```